# Converter QVector<QString> para int em C++

Tags: c++, qt

Possuo um QVector e quero converter ele para poder fazer comparações para descobrir qual o maior.

Tentei fazer isto mas não funciona:

```
QVector<QString> vector;
std::atoi(vector.value (i).toStdString ());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode converter uma QString para *int* usando a própria Qt:

```
vector.at( i ).toInt();
```

Ou, se precisar só do valor:

```
QVector<QString> vector;
vector << "1278" << "7" << "9";

int max = 0;
foreach (QString s, vector) {
   max = qMax( max, s.toInt() );
}

qDebug() << max;
```

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#toInt

Comment: Nem pensei em ver se existia um método no próprio QString. Muito obrigado

Comment: @GiovaniRaciPaganini a resposta do @Wakim ja era boa, mas optei por acrescentar um exemplo com `foreach`, que pode ser útil também, dependendo do seu caso prático.

Comment: Sim, acho valido colocar o exemplo, não pensei nisso no momento.

Answer (score 3):

Por incrível que pareça (de tão grande que é o QT) a classe `QString` possui um método que faz o parsing do conteúdo dela pra inteiro, da uma olhada em [`QString.toInt`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#toInt).

Comment: Agradeço pela ajuda.